# Handle bootstrap nav bar items overflow in angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and angular js. My requirement is, I want to display a horizontal nav bar elements when different options has selected from a drop down.
I want to handle the overflow of nav bar elements as a drop down. When there is a overflow of nav bar elements display as a drop down. when the window has re sized, based on the available width the elements to be placed and the remaining items should be displayed as drop down menu (not as a responsive menu).gge

ex url:http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-flexible-approach-to-responsive-navigation--webdesign-8397

The above example works fine in jquery but converting into angular js has problems.

ex image: https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/375_responsive_menu/img/step7.png

{{tab.name}}
                    
                    
                        {{tab.name}}
                        
                             0)}">
                                {{item.name}}
                                    0">
                                
                                
                                    
                                        {{itm.name}}